# How are do I specify both source and destination flags in the iptables FORWARD chain?

Tags: firewall, iptables

Since I a have iptables running on my router, it seems the only chain that works is the FORWARD chain to block traffic between the LAN and the internet.

In these FORWARD chain rules, like...

```
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -d 198.41.16.0/17 -j REJECT
```

...but since the router doesn't understand the direction of traffic, I essentially need two rules, like this...

```
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -d 198.41.16.0/17 -j REJECT
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -s 198.41.16.0/17 -j REJECT
```

Is there any way to combine them?  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, it is not possible to have an `iptables` command with (effectively) an OR match in it. I expect that the only way to get your desired outcome is to do two separate statements.

Best of luck!